# So I need to sort alphabeticlly structure data in pascal, I improvised a sorting method, but has an error idk how to fix

Tags: sorting, pascal

sorting system and the main problem starts from the "Until" function. I would like to hear someones opinion about what I did wrong, and if there is an easier solution, I will appreciate if u told me about it.
The idea of the problem is: you have n number of people, and u need do introduce each one from the keyboard. Then, I need to sort them alphabeticlly

```
uses crt;

type Data = record
day : 1..31;
month : 1..12;
year : integer;
end;

     Persoana = record
     Name : string;
     BirthDate : Data;
     end;
   
 
     ListaPersoane = array [1..50] of Persoana;
     
var x : ListaPersoane;    
    n:1..50;
    i,z,j,l,a,v:integer;
    y, k : longint;
    aux : string;
    
    begin
      
      writeln('Program created on: 13/10/2020;');
writeln('give the number of people (max. 50):');
readln(n);

  for i:=1 to n do begin
    
  ClrScr;
  writeln('Insert the name of person ', i, ': '); readln(x[i].Name);
  writeln('Insert the date o birth:'); writeln('day:'); readln(x[i].BirthDate.day);
  writeln('month:'); readln(x[i].BirthDate.month);
  writeln('year:'); readln(x[i].BirthDate.year);
  ClrScr;
  end;
 
  writeln('_______________________');
 for i:=1 to n do begin
 writeln(i, ') ', x[i].Name, '  ', x[i].BirthDate.day, '/', x[i].BirthDate.month, '/', x[i].BirthDate.year, ';');  
  writeln('_______________________');
 end;
 writeln();
      
      
      
      repeat
    k:=0;
for i:=1 to n do begin

  j:=1;
  repeat
  Inc(j);
  until (x[i].Name[j]>x[i].Name[j]) or (x[i].Name[j]<x[i].Name[j]);
  
  
  if(x[i].Name[j]>x[i+1].Name[j]) then begin
    aux:=x[i].Name;
    x[i].Name:=x[i+1].Name;
    x[i+1].Name:=aux;
    
    z:=x[i].BirthDate.day;
    x[i].BirthDate.day:=x[i+1].BirthDate.day;
    x[i+1].BirthDate.day:=z;
    
    l:=x[i].BirthDate.month;
    x[i].BirthDate.month:=x[i+1].BirthDate.month;
    x[i+1].BirthDate.month:=l;
    
    a:=x[i].BirthDate.year;
    x[i].BirthDate.year:=x[i+1].BirthDate.year;
    x[i+1].BirthDate.year:=a;
    Inc(k);
    end;
  
  
  
  
  
  end;
until (k=0);


  writeln('_______________________');
 for i:=1 to n do begin
 writeln(i, ') ', x[i].Name, '  ', x[i].BirthDate.day, '/', x[i].BirthDate.month, '/', x[i].BirthDate.year, ';');  
  writeln('_______________________');
 end;
 writeln();


    end.
```

Comment: Which Pascal compiler and IDE are you using?  These details should be in your q.

Comment: Im using PascalABC.NET as a compiler

Comment: That's a pity. Usually the best answers here explain how to debug a problem like this yourself, which is far more instructive than just telling you what your mistake is. Problem is, so few people here know about PascalABC that you'll be lucky to find someone who could explain how to use whatever debugging facilities it has. You should consider switching to FreePascal and its IDE, Lazarus - it is the most popular and widely used free Pascal compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that `PascalABC` can compare two strings and return which one is "smaller" or "bigger", without looping through the characters.

But to draw your attention to (at least) three issues in your sorting code, consider this code of yours:

```
  j := 1;
  repeat
    Inc(j);
  until (x[i].Name[j] > x[i].Name[j]) or (x[i].Name[j] < x[i].Name[j]);
```

Issue 1:
You initialize `j := 1` before the loop. Then before you use `j` to index a character, you increment it. Thus you never attempt to compare the first character.

Issue 2:
Your `repeat` loop doesn't take into consideration that names have a limited, and often different length.

Issue 3:
Will either of these conditions, on the `until` row, ever be true:

```
(x[i].Name[j] > x[i].Name[j])
```

or this:

```
(x[i].Name[j] < x[i].Name[j])
```

In the subsequent code you correctly compare a character in `x[i]` with `x[i+1]`

I leave the correction of these errors for you, yourself, to correct. Consult with your tutor if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much <3, I will ta care of the rest

Answer (score 0):

You have a repeat .. until which terminates when k=0. You start with k assigned 0, then never change k. Perhaps your repeat is terminating because you don’t change k in the loop.